# Multiple Importer/Exporter Methods with Different Parameters

Tags: c#, architecture, interface

I have 2 exporter methods (planning to have more) that essentially take my sprite definition from my sprite maker, and export that into a PNG file and an XML file that describes the PNG. Right now, I have stuffed these two methods into my Sprite class for testing, but they don't really belong there. So I thought it would be good if I made an interface for exporters and importers, then have one class for each type of importer/exporter, right?

Now the problem is that my two methods don't have the same parameters, so I can't use an Interface very easily.

The first exporter is a an "organized" exporter, and it exports the frames in a manner that humans can easily follow, no restrictions. It would just take the sprite definition, and a file name (with no extension) then produce the pair of files.

The second exporter is an optimally packed exporter and would take the same parameters plus a maximum width and height. Right now it's not optimal, it doesn't re-size the frames and it just picks the next slot that fits. Maybe there are additional options (parameters) that I have not thought of yet for this method.

The XML is identical for the existing exporters, but the PNG differs. Some time down the road, I might like to have other types of meta-data exporters, like JSON.

For the existing exporters, they both follow this pattern:

- Determine size of output PNG  (**Different** for each method)
- Make a Bitmap object with that size
- Set up, and start writing to my XML file
- Write out a bunch of meta-data that doesn't relate to the frames just yet
- Iterate through each sequence (a little more involved than it seems)

  - For each frame:

    - Figure out where the frame will go  (**Different** for each method)
    - Write information about this frame including sprite-sheet location & size from above
    - Draw the frame to the output bitmap at the location & size calculated above
- Save and close files

I can provide a link to the code on request.

(I added "Importer" to the question because I will want to add importers to these exporters one day)

Any suggestions on how I might pull these exporters out of my Sprite class and how to keep them related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be best if you create some base export class that has only some basic features shared between all export classes like `addSprite` or `saveToFile`. after that you can create some other classes which inherit this one plus they have specific functions to add saving parameters, something like this:

```
class baseExported
{
    public abstract void addSprite(Bitmap texture);
    public abstract bool export(String target);
};

class ExporterA : baseExporter
{
    public override void addSprite(...) {...};
    public override bool export(...) {...};
}

class ExporterB : baseExporter
{
    public override void addSprite(...) {...};
    public override void setMaxDimentions(int maxHeight,int maxWidth) {...};
    public override bool export(...) {...};
}

class ExporterC : baseExporter
{
    public override void addSprite(...) {...};
    public override void setMaxDimentions(int maxHeight,int maxWidth) {...};
    public override void addMetaData(String someData) {...};
    public override bool export(...) {...};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd define an exporter for each unique destination (PNG, XML, etc).
I'd then build Exporter classes that implemented one or more of those interfaces.
You might instantiate these through a factory ("Give me all the exporters that handle PNGs / images").  One of these would be the `SpriteExporter`.

A variation on this (but not an exclusive one) is to classify / organize exporters by input (what can they export).

Rather than say `IPNGExporter.ExportToPNG(Sprite)` you'd say `IPNGExporter.ExportToPNG(IExportable)`

You could take this further and say `IExportableToImage` but I don't see how that would really add much value off the top of my head.

Comment: Interesting, this is getting me thinking. The reason I had my exporters export 2 files is because both files are tightly coupled (one describes the other). I do like the idea of having different methods, if not different exporter classes altogether for each type of output though. I'll play around with this idea and let you know where I get to. Thanks